# Site Close Offer PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, message

I don't what exactly we say about this method..

Some time we visit to store or hosting service provider.. and when we are try to close a tab or windows its show us message..

[image: Reply Message]

and redirect to another page where we can see the offers/discount etc.

How could i do that?

***EDIT:***
Here is the link where you could see live demonstration
https://secure.ipower.com/register/registration.bml or home page of http://ipower.com

But i don't know how to use it...

Thanks,

Comment: You never tried to view the source of that page and see what they did?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The only sites that do this are spyware/malware sites. It's not a legitimate thing to do on any reputable/decent website.

Comment: Are you suggesting stack overflow isn't a reputable and decent website!?

Comment: @kissmyface try typing an answer on StackOverflow and navigate away... ;-) There are legitimate uses.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's not what's being described/requested though! And TBH that popup pisses me off. YES I'M SURE that's why I clicked the close button damn it. :-)

Comment: @N.B. i checked source code but i am good with javascript.. i think they use yahoo API to control these things..

Answer (score 2):

First hit on Google on "confirm leave web page":

> http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/exit_confirmation.php

```
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
```

Comment: its not helping me.. its always say the same message even i click on my own site link.. i need solution only show message popup if we close website page only.

Comment: Well I'm sorry, but I'm not helping you to alert a visitor every time they navigate away from your site. Only apply this to very specific occasions, since it's annoying as hell if it occurs on every page.

Comment: @Muhammad, one way is to make exceptions if you click any of your links. Another way is to make the js-track the posision of the cursor and check if you click the X-buttom. However, all this is a terrible mess, please avoid at all cost.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Actually sir i am running online store some time use coupon code and i want to display to all my visitors who close at checkout page.. some major hosting service provider do the same trick.. on checkout page use javascript when we are try to close page they show us discount detail but when we click on the same site link they did not show us any popup.  like ipage.com and greengeeks.com doing this some time..

Comment: @Muhammad The easiest way to do this is to add an `onclick` event to links that shouldn't display the message, which sets `window.onbeforeunload = null;`. This way, when you click one of these links you won't get the message, but for anything else which triggers `onbeforeunload` you will get the message.

Comment: I found the where they use javascript like what i wanted.  (https://secure.ipower.com/register/registration.bml)

or click on Getting Started at the home page of (http://ipower.com)

But i don't know how to use it.